# Finding a repeated string in a hex file

Tags: matlab

I have a relatively small hex file I need to find a pattern in with matlab and mark the addresses of each repetitions.

The file is 512kb in size; I only know the format of the pattern i'm looking for (16 byte long) and I know it is repeated only 2 or 3 times only in the whole file.

I suppose I would have to create a string containing the next 15 bytes for each positions, store then and compare them with all the previous strings as the program walk thru the file ? i'm not sure that's even an efficient process and most info I could find online for this kind of problem mostly related to processing text documents.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that you could fairly easily use regex for. The first thing to do is load the file into MATLAB in hex format, and convert it to a hex string:

```
fid = fopen(filename);
bindata = fread(fid,'*uint8'); % Reads the data into an array of type uint8
fclose(fid);
hexstr = sprintf('%x',bindata); % Converts the binary data to a hex string
```

This will give you a string that contains the data of the file in hexidecimal format, for instance `"4d41544c414220352e30..."`. It's then a fairly simple matter to use regex to search for your hex string:

```
startlocs = regexp(hextr,pattern);
```

Where `pattern` is the hexstring that you're searching for. `startlocs` will give you the starting location of each of the instances of the hex pattern (in bytes, starting from 1).

Comment: The problem is that "pattern" is not known from the start. Only it's length and the fact that it is an unique string of characters that only appear 2 times in the file is known.